# a texture that repeats across the world, based on X, Y coordinates

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, monogame

I'm using XNA/MonoGame to draw some 2D polygons for me. I'd like a Texture I have to repeat on multiple polygons, based on their X and Y coordinates.

here's an example of what I mean:

[image: texture example]

I had thought that doing something like this would work (assuming a 256x256 pixel texture)

```
verticies[0].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(blockX / 256f, (blockY + blockHeight) / 256f);
verticies[1].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(blockX / 256f, blockY / 256f);
verticies[2].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2((blockX + blockWidth) / 256f, (blockY + blockHeight) / 256f);
verticies[3].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2((blockX + blockWidth) / 256f, blockY / 256f);
// each block is draw with a TriangleStrip, hence the odd ordering of coordinates.
// the blocks I'm drawing are not on a fixed grid; their coordinates and dimensions are in pixels.
```

but the blocks end up "textured" with long-horizontal lines that look like the texture has been extremely stretched.

(to check if the problem had to do with TriangleStrips, I tried removing the last vertex and drawing a TriangleList of 1 - this had the same result on the texture, and the expected result of drawing only one half of my blocks.)

what's the correct way to achieve this effect?

Comment: Would using `%` instead of `/` work?

Comment: I have also tried (blockX % 256) / 256f, etc. this produces a weird, hard-to-describe (and wrong :P) visual effect. from what I've read online, though, values above 1.0 are desired anyway, as these inform the drawing functions to tile the texture, rather than attempting to stretch it to fit (http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/34072/xna-how-to-draw-some-sprites-tiled-wrapped-and-others-not). since my tiles may be wider and/or taller than the texture, tiling is definitely needed.

Comment: The "long, horizontal lines" you describe sound like the result of using a clamping sampler state.  What sampler state are you using?

Comment: I had tried "GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearWrap;" at one point, without success, and so had removed it, but trying it again, it works?! I've changed around some other code between then and now, so I guess I happen to have landed on the perfect combination. I think part of it has to do with how I'm alternating between drawing 3D stuff (for these textured rectangles) and 2D stuff (for everything else), which I also changed around recently. Though whether or not that was related... I don't know anything anymore :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my math was correct, but it seems that other code was wrong, and I was missing at least one important thing.

maybe-helpful hints for other people trying to achieve this effect and running into trouble:

```
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearWrap;
```

^ you need that code. but importantly, your SamplerState and other settings will get reset when you draw sprites (SpriteBatch's Begin()), so especially if you're abstracting your polygon-rendering code into little helper functions, be mindful of when and where you call them! ex:

```
spriteBatch.Begin();
// drawing sprites
MyFilledPolygonDrawer(args);
// drawing sprites
spriteBatch.End();
```

if you do this (assuming MyFilledPolygonDrawer uses 3D methods), you'll need to change all the settings (such as SamplerState) before you draw in 3D, and possibly after (depending on what settings you use for 2D rendering), all of which comes with a little overhead (and makes your code more fragile - you're more likely to screw up :P)

one way to avoid this is to draw all your 3D stuff and 2D stuff separately (all one, then all the other).

(in my case, I haven't got my code completely separated out in this way, but I was able to at least reduce some switching between 2D and 3D by using 2D methods to draw solid-color rectangles - [Draw Rectangle in XNA using SpriteBatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751732/draw-rectangle-in-xna-using-spritebatch#answer-5752115) - and 3D stuff only for less-regular and/or textured shapes.)

Comment: more-difficult alternative: if you can figure it out, it may be worth going 100% 2D by using Stencils to draw filled, irregular polygons, or going 100% 3D by using textured rectangles to draw sprites.