# Fill a 2D Rectangle

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, draw

I am new to XNA and right now I am drawing a rectangle using this code:

```
// Calculate particle intensity
intense = (int)((float)part.Life / PARTICLES_MAX_LIFE);
// Generate pen for the particle
pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(intense * m_Color.R , intense * m_Color.G, intense * m_Color.B));
// Draw particle
g.DrawRectangle(pen, part.Position.X, part.Position.Y, 
    Math.Max(1,8 * part.Life / PARTICLES_MAX_LIFE),
    Math.Max(1,8 * part.Life / PARTICLES_MAX_LIFE));
pen.Dispose();
```

All the ways to fill a rectangle with color that I found online dosen't seems to apply to the way I draw my rectangle. How can I fill it with color?

Comment: Are you sure this is XNA code?  This looks more like the GDI to me.

Comment: to be honest I found this code online and the thread was about particles in xna... but it still works as xna in visual studio

Comment: That definitely does not look like XNA at all. In XNA you can can draw  rectangle by making 1px x 1px texture and using SpriteBatch like this: `spriteBatch.Draw(pixelTexture, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), color);`

Comment: It works "as XNA" because XNA is still hosted inside of a Windows Form.  The GDI method to do what you want can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fillrectangle.aspx), but I would highly recommend learning more about actual XNA code before you continue development.  The [XNA Creator's Hub](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US) has a number of resources.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw Rectangle with XNA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792694/draw-rectangle-with-xna)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code appears to be most likely made for GDI and not XNA, therefor it is not working correctly.

However, XNA includes a very useful [`Rectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.aspx) structure.

This means that you can "stretch" an image to fill a rectangle, so create a new `Texture2D` that is 1x1 pixels, and stretch the dimensions when drawn to increase the size.. (Or you could load one)

```
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(graphics, 1, 1, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
texture.SetData<Color>(new Color[] { Color.White });
return texture;
```

You can use this small texture in conjunction with the [`Rectangle` based overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433986.aspx) method for `SpriteBatch`

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(X, Y, Width, Height), Color.White);
```

Change the `Width`, `Height`, Position and Color to your liking.