# Create Rounded Rectangle Texture2D

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I am building a game with dialog boxes, and I would like to be able to procedurally generate textures for the boxes, in a very similar style to that of the Final Fantasy Series (think like [Final Fantasy VII](http://i79.photobucket.com/albums/j148/Xngears/Final%20Fantasy/FFVII%20Retranslated/ff72009-03-1900-26-46-30.jpg)). Here is a code snippet of what I have so far:

```
public class DialogBox
{
    public Rectangle BoxArea { get; set; }
    public List<Color> BoxColors { get; set; }
    public List<Color> BorderColors { get; set; }
    public int BorderThickness { get; set; }
    public int BorderRadius { get; set; }
    private Texture2D texture;

    public void CreateBackdrop(ref GraphicsDevice graphics)
    {
        texture = new Texture2D(graphics,
                                BoxArea.Width,
                                BoxArea.Height,
                                true,
                                SurfaceFormat.Color);
        Color[] color = new Color[texture.Width * texture.Height];

        for(int x = 0; x < texture.Width; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < texture.Height; y++)
            {
                switch(BoxColors.Count)
                {
                    case 4:
                        Color leftColor = Color.Lerp(BoxColor[0], BoxColor[1], (y / (texture.Height - 1)));
                        Color rightColor = Color.Lerp(BoxColor[2], BoxColor[3], (y / (texture.Height - 1)));
                        color[x + y * texture.Width] = Color.Lerp(leftColor,
                                                                  RightColor,
                                                                  (x / (texture.Width - 1)));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        color[x + y * texture.Width] = Color.Lerp(BoxColors[0],
                                                                  BoxColors[1],
                                                                  (x / (texture.Width - 1)));
                        break;
                    default:
                        color[x + y * texture.Width];
                        break;
                 }
            }
        }
        texture.SetData<Color>(color);
    }
}
```

What I am looking for is the following:

- 4-way gradient color (implemented)
- Rounded Rectangle
- Border with gradient

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I figured out the rectangle via [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792694/draw-rectangle-with-xna).

Comment: Are you aware of the technique called "Scale 9 Grid"? 


http://despre.md/ideapress/what-is-scale9grid/

Comment: @Goose I understood that technique exists, but I had originally thought since I would be handling this all dynamically, that would not work as well for me. I will take a look at what I have and see if I can integrate that knowledge into what I am doing.

Comment: You are correct. It doesn't make much sense if you want to create the shapes dynamically. I suggest it only as an alternative to creating the shapes dynamically. Scale9grid allows you to use textures to make arbitrarily size windows. It just depends on what your goal is.

Comment: @Goose My goal is to be able to create these textures procedurally at runtime. Honestly, it does not behoove anyone with artistic skills, but for those of us who lack those talents, it will give us a way to create simple rounded rectangles for a dialog box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out what I was having trouble with; calculating the corner arcs. What I figured out was that one could use distance from a point to understand the way to draw the border, rather than using mathematics to calculate the points within a circle. Below I have posted the code to generate the rounded rectangle.

```
public Texture2D CreateRoundedRectangleTexture(GraphicsDevice graphics, int width, int height, int borderThickness, int borderRadius, int borderShadow, List<Color> backgroundColors, List<Color> borderColors, float initialShadowIntensity, float finalShadowIntensity)
{
    if (backgroundColors == null || backgroundColors.Count == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Must define at least one background color (up to four).");
    if (borderColors == null || borderColors.Count == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Must define at least one border color (up to three).");
    if (borderRadius < 1) throw new ArgumentException("Must define a border radius (rounds off edges).");
    if (borderThickness < 1) throw new ArgumentException("Must define border thikness.");
    if (borderThickness + borderRadius > height / 2 || borderThickness + borderRadius > width / 2) throw new ArgumentException("Border will be too thick and/or rounded to fit on the texture.");
    if (borderShadow > borderRadius) throw new ArgumentException("Border shadow must be lesser in magnitude than the border radius (suggeted: shadow <= 0.25 * radius).");

    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(graphics, width, height, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
    Color[] color = new Color[width * height];

    for (int x = 0; x < texture.Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < texture.Height; y++)
        {
            switch (backgroundColors.Count)
            {
                case 4:
                    Color leftColor0 = Color.Lerp(backgroundColors[0], backgroundColors[1], ((float)y / (width - 1)));
                    Color rightColor0 = Color.Lerp(backgroundColors[2], backgroundColors[3], ((float)y / (height - 1)));
                    color[x + width * y] = Color.Lerp(leftColor0, rightColor0, ((float)x / (width - 1)));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Color leftColor1 = Color.Lerp(backgroundColors[0], backgroundColors[1], ((float)y / (width - 1)));
                    Color rightColor1 = Color.Lerp(backgroundColors[1], backgroundColors[2], ((float)y / (height - 1)));
                    color[x + width * y] = Color.Lerp(leftColor1, rightColor1, ((float)x / (width - 1)));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    color[x + width * y] = Color.Lerp(backgroundColors[0], backgroundColors[1], ((float)x / (width - 1)));
                    break;
                default:
                    color[x + width * y] = backgroundColors[0];
                    break;
            }

            color[x + width * y] = ColorBorder(x, y, width, height, borderThickness, borderRadius, borderShadow, color[x + width * y], borderColors, initialShadowIntensity, finalShadowIntensity);
        }
    }

    texture.SetData<Color>(color);
    return texture;
}

private Color ColorBorder(int x, int y, int width, int height, int borderThickness, int borderRadius, int borderShadow, Color initialColor, List<Color> borderColors, float initialShadowIntensity, float finalShadowIntensity)
{
    Rectangle internalRectangle = new Rectangle((borderThickness + borderRadius), (borderThickness + borderRadius), width - 2 * (borderThickness + borderRadius), height - 2 * (borderThickness + borderRadius));

    if (internalRectangle.Contains(x, y)) return initialColor;

    Vector2 origin = Vector2.Zero;
    Vector2 point = new Vector2(x, y);

    if (x < borderThickness + borderRadius)
    {
        if (y < borderRadius + borderThickness)
            origin = new Vector2(borderRadius + borderThickness, borderRadius + borderThickness);
        else if (y > height - (borderRadius + borderThickness))
            origin = new Vector2(borderRadius + borderThickness, height - (borderRadius + borderThickness));
        else
            origin = new Vector2(borderRadius + borderThickness, y);
    }
    else if (x > width - (borderRadius + borderThickness))
    {
        if (y < borderRadius + borderThickness)
            origin = new Vector2(width - (borderRadius + borderThickness), borderRadius + borderThickness);
        else if (y > height - (borderRadius + borderThickness))
            origin = new Vector2(width - (borderRadius + borderThickness), height - (borderRadius + borderThickness));
        else
            origin = new Vector2(width - (borderRadius + borderThickness), y);
    }
    else
    {
        if (y < borderRadius + borderThickness)
            origin = new Vector2(x, borderRadius + borderThickness);
        else if (y > height - (borderRadius + borderThickness))
            origin = new Vector2(x, height - (borderRadius + borderThickness));
    }

    if (!origin.Equals(Vector2.Zero))
    {
        float distance = Vector2.Distance(point, origin);

        if (distance > borderRadius + borderThickness + 1)
        {
            return Color.Transparent;
        }
        else if (distance > borderRadius + 1)
        {
            if (borderColors.Count > 2)
            {
                float modNum = distance - borderRadius;

                if (modNum < borderThickness / 2)
                {
                    return Color.Lerp(borderColors[2], borderColors[1], (float)((modNum) / (borderThickness / 2.0)));
                }
                else
                {
                    return Color.Lerp(borderColors[1], borderColors[0], (float)((modNum - (borderThickness / 2.0)) / (borderThickness / 2.0)));
                }
            }


            if (borderColors.Count > 0)
                return borderColors[0];
        }
        else if (distance > borderRadius - borderShadow + 1)
        {
            float mod = (distance - (borderRadius - borderShadow)) / borderShadow;
            float shadowDiff = initialShadowIntensity - finalShadowIntensity;
            return DarkenColor(initialColor, ((shadowDiff * mod) + finalShadowIntensity));
        }
    }

    return initialColor;
}

private Color DarkenColor(Color color, float shadowIntensity)
{
    return Color.Lerp(color, Color.Black, shadowIntensity);
}
```

With all of the code above, this is the result:
[image: Rounded Texture in Action]