# Create smoothly rounded rectangle with Texture2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, smoothing

I am trying to draw rounded rectangles which can be used as a Texture for any UI component. My goal is to create this rounded Texture with the `Texture2D` class by setting the pixels with the [`SetPixels32`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels32.html) function. I do not want to do this with a shader.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17260476/3785314) did that but with XNA instead of Unity. I ported it into Unity *but the Edge is jaggy*.

This is what it looks like in Unity:

[image]

Below is the ported code:

```
public int width = 256;
public int height = 140;
public int borderThickness = 1;  //Cannot be < 1
//Border shadow cannot be more than Border Radius
public int borderRadius = 40; //Cannot be < 1
public int borderShadow = 2;
public List<Color32> backgroundColors = new List<Color32>();
public List<Color32> borderColors = new List<Color32>();
public float initialShadowIntensity = 5f;
public float finalShadowIntensity = 5f;


private Texture2D resultTex;
public RawImage display;

void Start()
{
    backgroundColors.Add(new Color32(171, 0, 0, 255));
    backgroundColors.Add(new Color32(9, 48, 173, 255));

    borderColors.Add(new Color32(111, 8, 99, 255));
    borderColors.Add(new Color32(171, 4, 161, 255));

    resultTex = RectangleCreator.
        CreateRoundedRectangleTexture(width, height, borderThickness,
        borderRadius, borderShadow, backgroundColors, borderColors,
        initialShadowIntensity, finalShadowIntensity);

    display.texture = resultTex;
    display.SetNativeSize();
}



public class RectangleCreator
{
    public static Texture2D CreateRoundedRectangleTexture(int width, int height, int borderThickness, int borderRadius, int borderShadow, List<Color32> backgroundColors, List<Color32> borderColors, float initialShadowIntensity, float finalShadowIntensity)
    {
        if (backgroundColors == null || backgroundColors.Count == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Must define at least one background color (up to four).");
        if (borderColors == null || borderColors.Count == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Must define at least one border color (up to three).");
        if (borderRadius < 1) throw new ArgumentException("Must define a border radius (rounds off edges).");
        if (borderThickness < 1) throw new ArgumentException("Must define border thikness.");
        if (borderThickness + borderRadius > height / 2 || borderThickness + borderRadius > width / 2) throw new ArgumentException("Border will be too thick and/or rounded to fit on the texture.");
        if (borderShadow > borderRadius) throw new ArgumentException("Border shadow must be lesser in magnitude than the border radius (suggeted: shadow <= 0.25 * radius).");

        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
        Color32[] color = new Color32[width * height];

        for (int x = 0; x < texture.width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < texture.height; y++)
            {
                switch (backgroundColors.Count)
                {
                    case 4:
                        Color32 leftColor0 = Color32.Lerp(backgroundColors[0], backgroundColors[1], ((float)y / (width - 1)));
                        Color32 rightColor0 = Color32.Lerp(backgroundColors[2], backgroundColors[3], ((float)y / (height - 1)));
                        color[x + width * y] = Color32.Lerp(leftColor0, rightColor0, ((float)x / (width - 1)));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Color32 leftColor1 = Color32.Lerp(backgroundColors[0], backgroundColors[1], ((float)y / (width - 1)));
                        Color32 rightColor1 = Color32.Lerp(backgroundColors[1], backgroundColors[2], ((float)y / (height - 1)));
                        color[x + width * y] = Color32.Lerp(leftColor1, rightColor1, ((float)x / (width - 1)));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        color[x + width * y] = Color32.Lerp(backgroundColors[0], backgroundColors[1], ((float)x / (width - 1)));
                        break;
                    default:
                        color[x + width * y] = backgroundColors[0];
                        break;
                }

                color[x + width * y] = ColorBorder(x, y, width, height, borderThickness, borderRadius, borderShadow, color[x + width * y], borderColors, initialShadowIntensity, finalShadowIntensity);
            }
        }

        texture.SetPixels32(color);
        texture.Apply();
        return texture;
    }

    private static Color32 ColorBorder(int x, int y, int width, int height, int borderThickness, int borderRadius, int borderShadow, Color32 initialColor, List<Color32> borderColors, float initialShadowIntensity, float finalShadowIntensity)
    {
        Rect internalRectangle = new Rect((borderThickness + borderRadius), (borderThickness + borderRadius), width - 2 * (borderThickness + borderRadius), height - 2 * (borderThickness + borderRadius));


        Vector2 point = new Vector2(x, y);
        if (internalRectangle.Contains(point)) return initialColor;

        Vector2 origin = Vector2.zero;

        if (x < borderThickness + borderRadius)
        {
            if (y < borderRadius + borderThickness)
                origin = new Vector2(borderRadius + borderThickness, borderRadius + borderThickness);
            else if (y > height - (borderRadius + borderThickness))
                origin = new Vector2(borderRadius + borderThickness, height - (borderRadius + borderThickness));
            else
                origin = new Vector2(borderRadius + borderThickness, y);
        }
        else if (x > width - (borderRadius + borderThickness))
        {
            if (y < borderRadius + borderThickness)
                origin = new Vector2(width - (borderRadius + borderThickness), borderRadius + borderThickness);
            else if (y > height - (borderRadius + borderThickness))
                origin = new Vector2(width - (borderRadius + borderThickness), height - (borderRadius + borderThickness));
            else
                origin = new Vector2(width - (borderRadius + borderThickness), y);
        }
        else
        {
            if (y < borderRadius + borderThickness)
                origin = new Vector2(x, borderRadius + borderThickness);
            else if (y > height - (borderRadius + borderThickness))
                origin = new Vector2(x, height - (borderRadius + borderThickness));
        }

        if (!origin.Equals(Vector2.zero))
        {
            float distance = Vector2.Distance(point, origin);

            if (distance > borderRadius + borderThickness + 1)
            {
                return Color.clear;
            }
            else if (distance > borderRadius + 1)
            {
                if (borderColors.Count > 2)
                {
                    float modNum = distance - borderRadius;

                    if (modNum < borderThickness / 2)
                    {
                        return Color32.Lerp(borderColors[2], borderColors[1], (float)((modNum) / (borderThickness / 2.0)));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Color32.Lerp(borderColors[1], borderColors[0], (float)((modNum - (borderThickness / 2.0)) / (borderThickness / 2.0)));
                    }
                }


                if (borderColors.Count > 0)
                    return borderColors[0];
            }
            else if (distance > borderRadius - borderShadow + 1)
            {
                float mod = (distance - (borderRadius - borderShadow)) / borderShadow;
                float shadowDiff = initialShadowIntensity - finalShadowIntensity;
                return DarkenColor(initialColor, ((shadowDiff * mod) + finalShadowIntensity));
            }
        }

        return initialColor;
    }

    private static Color32 DarkenColor(Color32 color, float shadowIntensity)
    {
        return Color32.Lerp(color, Color.black, shadowIntensity);
    }
}
```

I tried fixing the black jagged edge by replacing the

```
return Color32.Lerp(color, Color.black, shadowIntensity);
```

with

```
return Color32.Lerp(color, Color.clear, shadowIntensity);
```

but that didn't smooth it with a transparent color. It removed the black color but made it more jagged.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

How can I smooth out the texture edge?

Comment: What is the FilterMode of Texture2D? Can you set it to “point” and try again, or did you already try it?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea and I just did and it still looks better. The jagged issue is still there. It just improved a little bit.

Comment: If you want to go off the deep end, you could implement this shader: https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/valve/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf

Comment: @LeoBartkus Yes, I know I can use shader for that but I mentioned in my question that I don't want to use shader.  I prefer to use the Texture class for this.

Comment: Ah, I would try doubling the resolution and rendering this with the material set to cutout mode.  You could also be running into the half-pixel problem or your original codebase's workaround for it. http://drilian.com/2008/11/25/understanding-half-pixel-and-half-texel-offsets/

Comment: @LeoBartkus I will try doubling the res. If you have an answer, you can put answer as I plan to put bounty on this today. Doubling the resolution seems like something that would solve this.

Comment: I just tried your code, and I'm not seeing the problem.  What kind of thing is this behavior attached to?   I have a feeling the problem is related to your camera or viewport setup.  I'm also not seeing the aliasing artifacts around the edges that are in your screenshot.

Comment: It can be attached to anything but I think it's currently attached to the camera right now. Now on my computer right now to verify. The issue is the non smoothed sections especially on the rounded edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I take this code and put it on a RawImage in a UICanvas it looks fine.  This is default setup you get with Game Object -> UI -> Raw Image

I just attached the component to the rawimage and set the Display property to itself;

[image: My hierarchy]

[image: My Results]

[image: Zoomed with pixel grid]

If you want unity to do some antialiasing, you can increase the resolution of the raw image and remove the call to `display.SetNativeSize();`  But then you will need to set the actual size of the rectangle using its transform component.

```
   using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {


public int width = 256;
public int height = 140;
public int borderThickness = 1;  //Cannot be < 1
//Border shadow cannot be more than Border Radius
public int borderRadius = 40; //Cannot be < 1
public int borderShadow = 2;
public List<Color32> backgroundColors = new List<Color32>();
public List<Color32> borderColors = new List<Color32>();
public float initialShadowIntensity = 5f;
public float finalShadowIntensity = 5f;

public float resolutionmultiplier = 4f;


private Texture2D resultTex;
public RawImage display;

public RectTransform rt;

void Start()
{
    backgroundColors.Add(new Color32(171, 0, 0, 255));
    backgroundColors.Add(new Color32(9, 48, 173, 255));

    borderColors.Add(new Color32(111, 8, 99, 255));
    borderColors.Add(new Color32(171, 4, 161, 255));

    resultTex = RectangleCreator.
        CreateRoundedRectangleTexture(4, width, height, borderThickness,
        borderRadius, borderShadow, backgroundColors, borderColors,
        initialShadowIntensity, finalShadowIntensity);

    display.texture = resultTex;
    rt.sizeDelta = new Vector2(width, height);
}



public class RectangleCreator
{
    public static Texture2D CreateRoundedRectangleTexture(int resolutionmultiplier, int width, int height, int borderThickness, int borderRadius, int borderShadow, List<Color32> backgroundColors, List<Color32> borderColors, float initialShadowIntensity, float finalShadowIntensity)
    {
       // if (backgroundColors == null || backgroundColors.Count == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Must define at least one background color (up to four).");
      //  if (borderColors == null || borderColors.Count == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Must define at least one border color (up to three).");
      //  if (borderRadius < 1) throw new ArgumentException("Must define a border radius (rounds off edges).");
      //  if (borderThickness < 1) throw new ArgumentException("Must define border thikness.");
     //   if (borderThickness + borderRadius > height / 2 || borderThickness + borderRadius > width / 2) throw new ArgumentException("Border will be too thick and/or rounded to fit on the texture.");
     //   if (borderShadow > borderRadius) throw new ArgumentException("Border shadow must be lesser in magnitude than the border radius (suggeted: shadow <= 0.25 * radius).");

        width = width * resolutionmultiplier;
        height = height * resolutionmultiplier;

        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
        Color32[] color = new Color32[width * height];

        for (int x = 0; x < texture.width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < texture.height; y++)
            {
                switch (backgroundColors.Count)
                {
                    case 4:
                        Color32 leftColor0 = Color32.Lerp(backgroundColors[0], backgroundColors[1], ((float)y / (width - 1)));
                        Color32 rightColor0 = Color32.Lerp(backgroundColors[2], backgroundColors[3], ((float)y / (height - 1)));
                        color[x + width * y] = Color32.Lerp(leftColor0, rightColor0, ((float)x / (width - 1)));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Color32 leftColor1 = Color32.Lerp(backgroundColors[0], backgroundColors[1], ((float)y / (width - 1)));
                        Color32 rightColor1 = Color32.Lerp(backgroundColors[1], backgroundColors[2], ((float)y / (height - 1)));
                        color[x + width * y] = Color32.Lerp(leftColor1, rightColor1, ((float)x / (width - 1)));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        color[x + width * y] = Color32.Lerp(backgroundColors[0], backgroundColors[1], ((float)x / (width - 1)));
                        break;
                    default:
                        color[x + width * y] = backgroundColors[0];
                        break;
                }

                color[x + width * y] = ColorBorder(x, y, width, height, borderThickness, borderRadius, borderShadow, color[x + width * y], borderColors, initialShadowIntensity, finalShadowIntensity);
            }
        }

        texture.SetPixels32(color);
        texture.Apply();
        return texture;
    }

    private static Color32 ColorBorder(int x, int y, int width, int height, int borderThickness, int borderRadius, int borderShadow, Color32 initialColor, List<Color32> borderColors, float initialShadowIntensity, float finalShadowIntensity)
    {
        Rect internalRectangle = new Rect((borderThickness + borderRadius), (borderThickness + borderRadius), width - 2 * (borderThickness + borderRadius), height - 2 * (borderThickness + borderRadius));


        Vector2 point = new Vector2(x, y);
        if (internalRectangle.Contains(point)) return initialColor;

        Vector2 origin = Vector2.zero;

        if (x < borderThickness + borderRadius)
        {
            if (y < borderRadius + borderThickness)
                origin = new Vector2(borderRadius + borderThickness, borderRadius + borderThickness);
            else if (y > height - (borderRadius + borderThickness))
                origin = new Vector2(borderRadius + borderThickness, height - (borderRadius + borderThickness));
            else
                origin = new Vector2(borderRadius + borderThickness, y);
        }
        else if (x > width - (borderRadius + borderThickness))
        {
            if (y < borderRadius + borderThickness)
                origin = new Vector2(width - (borderRadius + borderThickness), borderRadius + borderThickness);
            else if (y > height - (borderRadius + borderThickness))
                origin = new Vector2(width - (borderRadius + borderThickness), height - (borderRadius + borderThickness));
            else
                origin = new Vector2(width - (borderRadius + borderThickness), y);
        }
        else
        {
            if (y < borderRadius + borderThickness)
                origin = new Vector2(x, borderRadius + borderThickness);
            else if (y > height - (borderRadius + borderThickness))
                origin = new Vector2(x, height - (borderRadius + borderThickness));
        }

        if (!origin.Equals(Vector2.zero))
        {
            float distance = Vector2.Distance(point, origin);

            if (distance > borderRadius + borderThickness + 1)
            {
                return Color.clear;
            }
            else if (distance > borderRadius + 1)
            {
                if (borderColors.Count > 2)
                {
                    float modNum = distance - borderRadius;

                    if (modNum < borderThickness / 2)
                    {
                        return Color32.Lerp(borderColors[2], borderColors[1], (float)((modNum) / (borderThickness / 2.0)));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Color32.Lerp(borderColors[1], borderColors[0], (float)((modNum - (borderThickness / 2.0)) / (borderThickness / 2.0)));
                    }
                }


                if (borderColors.Count > 0)
                    return borderColors[0];
            }
            else if (distance > borderRadius - borderShadow + 1)
            {
                float mod = (distance - (borderRadius - borderShadow)) / borderShadow;
                float shadowDiff = initialShadowIntensity - finalShadowIntensity;
                return DarkenColor(initialColor, ((shadowDiff * mod) + finalShadowIntensity));
            }
        }

        return initialColor;
    }

    private static Color32 DarkenColor(Color32 color, float shadowIntensity)
    {
        return Color32.Lerp(color, Color.black, shadowIntensity);
    }
}
}
```

[image: Anti aliased version]

**EDIT:**

After increasing the texture resolution width, height to about `2048`, `624`, increase the `borderRadius` to `300`. Finally make sure that *"Low Resolution Aspect Ratios"* is not enabled on the Game View. This causes the image to be blurry.

[image]

Comment: I got what's in my first screenshot with the rounded jagged edges

Comment: Your code lines up pixels in screen space exactly.  Just like it would in XNA.

Comment: Wait, is your viewport scale set to 1x in the game view tab?

Comment: Nope. At the time of posting this, that wasn't an issue. I will do the changes you recommended when I get back to my computer

Comment: I can't believe I wasted so much time on this. There is a new check box in Unity named *"Low Resolution Aspect Ratios"* and it is enabled by default. I simply disabled that and it works fine after also increasing the texture size as you suggested. I also had to change the `borderRadius` to about `300` since I changed the resolution. It's now smooth. Thanks.